# SF-1 App Navigation API

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've developed a custom VF page which uses a custom APEX controller. I was wondering how for instance navigate back to the SF-1 main page / feed after an action is complete for instance.
I've tried invoking the sforce.one.navigateToSObject command but not entirely sure how to point it to the SF-1 default page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual home page of Salesforce1 can be configured by the system administrator - I haven't found a way to get at that information.

The following JavaScript takes me back to the default main page though (on my iOS installed application at any rate) aka the 'feed' in the menu:

```
sforce.one.navigateToURL('/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage');
```

I got the idea from the throwaway line at the end of the following doc link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm

> Calls to sforce.one.navigateToURL may result in an “Unsupported Page”
>   error if the URL references standard pages for objects or Chatter
>   pages. To avoid this error, ensure that the URL begins with a
>   backslash (/_ui instead of _ui).

Comment: This is a nice little gem Keir, how did you figure it out?

Comment: What if you don't have Chatter and Publisher actions enabled. How can I get to the main home page on S1, any ideas? thx