# Download of file in window.open popup

Tags: salesforce1-app, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am working on integrating third party application with Salesforce. As part of a use case, I am opening third party URL window popup using window.open() and hitting download file button present on that page.

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="window.open('third-party-url','Popup');" value="Click Here"/>
```

When I perform this action using Salesforce Web, the third party URL opens up in a new pop-up window, where on click of download button the file gets downloaded.

When I try it on Salesforce1 on any android mobile, it opens a pop-up window within salesforce. But on click of download button, the file doesn't get downloaded. I have compared the HTTP response that we get for both the download requests (from the Web and android mobile) - both return 200 OK response with **raw data of file content in the response**. But I don't see the file getting downloaded on the device. I have tried searching for the file in device's file manager everywhere but I don't see it. Is there a particular place where this would get downloaded? Given that the HTTP response has complete raw data of the file, it should have gotten downloaded and stored on the device.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For navigating to 3rd Party Url in Salesforce 1 you need to use 
**sforce.one.navigateToURL("​third-party-url"​[, isredirect])** 
as described in the link: [sforce.one object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm)
You can also have a look at this StackeExchnage post [Salesforce1 navigateToURL method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44148/salesforce1-navigatetourl-method)

for a deep dive. Please note that 3rd Party url in SF1 will be opened up in mobile browser separately.